# AdMob integration on iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, admob, ads

I want to show advertisement through AdMob. I got AdMob SDK from google document. But, i just confused that to get Publisher id. I read some blogs include google document, gave a way to get publisher id Link is  http://www.admob.com/my_sites/.. But, now my iphone application is in developing stage, how do i know my app stoer link? Then how can i get Publisher id? and Where i can give advertise for AdMob? How can i test AdMob in iPhone Simulator and Device? I got a sample code from google site Link is http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/ios/intermediate.html#testdevices. They gave a sample code,

```
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];      request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,                               // Simulator
@"28ab37c3902621dd572509110745071f0101b124",    // Test iPhone 3G 3.0.1
@"8cf09e81ef3ec5418c3450f7954e0e95db8ab200",    // Test iPod 4.3.1
nil];
```

i implement this code in my app error through like 'testDevices' something structure or union..  Can you please help me friends... Thanks to spent your valuable time with me..

Please help me friends....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my AdMob problem. I got my publisher id by this way

1. Login your AdMob account
2. Go to Sites&Apps.
3. View your sites given below, which are developed by you.
4. Just move curser to the app or site, two boxes will show named as Reporting and Manage Settings.
5. Hit Manage Settings and view your Publisher id there.

Note: Your iphone or iPad name and your admob app name should be same. Then AdMob will run on simulator also.